# Dice Doubles Java Exercise - Logical Error

Tags: java

I am a beginner learning Java on my own via online sources. I have come across this exercise.

> Write a program that simulates a dice roll by picking a random number from 1-6 and then picking a second random number from 1-6. Add the two values together, and display the total. Modify your dice game so that it keeps rolling until they get doubles (the same number on both dice).

I have this code so far:

```
public class DiceGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("ROLL THE DICE!\n");

    int firstRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);

    int secondRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);

    while (firstRoll != secondRoll) {
        System.out.println("Roll #1: " + firstRoll);
        System.out.println("Roll #2: " + secondRoll);
        int total = firstRoll + secondRoll;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total);
    }
    System.out.println("You rolled doubles!");
    System.out.println("Roll #1: " + firstRoll);
    System.out.println("Roll #2: " + secondRoll);
    int total = firstRoll + secondRoll;
    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
}
}
```

The issue is that when I run this code, if both rolls aren't the same, the program runs forever outputting the same first and second roll values and total...I'm sure I have a logical error with the while loop. Please help.

Here is an example of my output:

```
Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 3
The total is 5
```

(The while condition keeps returning false and printing the same values)

Here is an example of the desired output:

```
Roll #1: 3
Roll #2: 5
The total is 8

Roll #1: 6
Roll #2: 1
The total is 7

Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 5
The total is 7

Roll #1: 1
Roll #2: 1
The total is 2
```

(The program should end upon rolling doubles)

Comment: you need to "reroll" the dices if they are not equal (in your while loop) currently you just add them together infinitly without changing the values of the two "roles"

Comment: put
firstRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
secondRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6); as your last statement inside while loop

Comment: Obviously, the probability that you will get the same couple two times is 1/36 and it is astronomically infinitesimal when you roll 3 couples. You should open a debugger to see the flow of control. That is called a `debugging`. Learning the debugging yourself, you will be almost like a magitian, able to answer the questions yourself. It is a reprehensible practice to ask to debug your program at SO. Also, the  rule of thumb is to eliminate duplicates from your code (google DRY principle). You factor the common piece of code out (I see println("Roll 1,2") repeats twice).

Answer (score 2):

You have to roll the dice again it their values are not same.

Using `do-while` is good in this case.

```
int firstRoll, secondRoll;
do {
    firstRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    secondRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    System.out.println("Roll #1: " + firstRoll);
    System.out.println("Roll #2: " + secondRoll);
    int total = firstRoll + secondRoll;
    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
} while (firstRoll != secondRoll);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the roll again at each iteration:

```
while (firstRoll != secondRoll) {
    System.out.println("Roll #1: " + firstRoll);
    System.out.println("Roll #2: " + secondRoll);
    int total = firstRoll + secondRoll;
    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
    firstRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    secondRoll = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
}
```

Comment: Yes; but a `do/while` loop would avoid the need to duplicate the assignments of `firstRoll` and `secondRoll`.

Comment: true of course, with a bit of changing the way the statements are printed.
It is also better to have a method for the roll.

I merely wanted to provide a clear answer as to what was missing without changing too much code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write a method `public int roll()` and put there logic for calculating random number between 1-6. You are just OUTPUTTING the result of firstRoll and secondRoll instead of calculating it again in a method.

Example:

```
    public class Dice() {
        public int roll() {
         return 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
        }
    }
```

and use it:

```
Dice d1 = new Dice();
Dice d2 = new Dice();

int d1Result = d1.roll();
int d1Result = d2.roll();

while (d1Result != d2Result) {
d1Result = d1.roll();
d2Result = d2.roll();

System.out.println("Result d1: " + d1Result);
System.out.println("Result d2: " + d2Result);
 // Rest of logic ... 

}
```

Comment: Great appoach. I haven't learned to create and use methods yet :P Any good sources online to practice Java by the way??

Comment: I suggest reading Oracle guides and tutorials :-) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/ Especially Object Oriented Paradigm (Methods, Classes etc..)